# ¿Está bien el uso del punto y coma en la siguiente frase? "Cuando no pude.... decidí estudiar español; y ahora lo hablo a nivel avanzado"

Tags: puntuación

¿Está bien el uso del punto y coma en la siguiente frase?

> Cuando no pude entrar el departamento de filología hispánica en la universidad, decidí estudiar español por mi cuenta por internet; y ahora lo hablo a nivel avanzado.

¿O es mejor usar una coma o qué?

Answer (score 3):

En el caso del ejemplo que planteas, dado que usas la conjunción *y* no es necesario el uso de ningún signo de puntuación:

> Cuando no pude entrar en el departamento de Filología Hispánica en la universidad, decidí estudiar español por mi cuenta por Internet y ahora lo hablo a nivel avanzado.

Si omites la conjunción, sí es posible usar un signo de puntuación:

> Cuando no pude entrar en el departamento de Filología Hispánica en la universidad, decidí estudiar español por mi cuenta por Internet. Ahora lo hablo a nivel avanzado.
>
> Cuando no pude entrar en el departamento de Filología Hispánica en la universidad, decidí estudiar español por mi cuenta por Internet; ahora lo hablo a nivel avanzado.

Como nota, el uso de "cuando no pude entrar" me suena un poquito forzado. Yo lo escribiría así:

> Al no poder entrar en el departamento...
>
> Cuando vi que no iba a entrar en el departamento...

Comment: Muy buena respuesta. A mí también me suena raro el _cuando no pude entrar_ y tu sugerencia de usar _al no poder..._ encaja mejor: al fin y al cabo hablamos de causalidad, no de sucesos paralelos. Nótese por cierto que el punto y coma sirve para crear una mini pausa dramática, que se marca aún más con el "y" inicial. Pero sí, un punto suena mejor.